# Tables from JPA Entities Eclipse & DB2

Tags: eclipse, jpa, db2

I am using Eclipse Kepler EE and DB2 UDB V10.5 with JPA 2.0(Open JPA).

I can create model classes(JPA Entities) from tables but I can't create tables from JPA Entities.

How can I connect Eclipse to DB2 so that I can see tables on DB2 when I run my project on Eclipse?

PS: I searched in stackoverflow and I didn't find the exact thing I want in the previous questions.

Comment: All JPA implementations provide ways of creating tables for the entities, and JPA 2.1 standardises it. You don't say which JPA implementation you're using.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using JPA 2.0.

Comment: errrm, so why not name what your JPA implementation is ????

Comment: @BillyFrost I don't understand what you are asking for?

Comment: A JPA implementation provides JPA persistence. It will be something like Hibernate, DataNucleus, EclipseLink, OpenJPA. I'd suggest you read up on JPA if you're going to use it

Comment: @furbmely, JPA is a specification, there are several implementations (such as Hibernate) of this specification. What is asked for is which implementation of JPA that you are using.

Comment: @BillyFrost it's OpenJPA

Answer (score 0):

If its OpenJPA, then why not search in their documentation? A simple search gives
http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.3.0/apache-openjpa/docs/manual.html#ref_guide_mapping_synch
which explains how to generate tables